# Difference in usage between "раба" and "рабыня"

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова, синонимы

Several years ago I have heard that the correct title of soap-opera "Рабыня Изаура" is "Раба Изаура", though the translators picked "рабыня" instead. Though, I see that Даль lists рабыня, раба, рабица as synonyms.

Is there a difference in usage between these words (semantical, stylistical, etc.)?

The only example I can think of is "раба божия" (church term) vs. "рабыня божия" (never heard such expression).

---

Несколько лет назад я где-то услышал что сериал "Рабыня Изаура" по-правильному должен называться "Раба Изаура", но переводчики почему-то выбрали слово "рабыня". В то же время в словаре Даля раба, рабыня и рабица перечислены как синонимы.

Есть ли различие в употреблении этих слов (семантическое, стилистическое и т.д.)?

Единственный пример который мне приходит на ум это церковное "раба божия", которое не употребляется как "рабыня божия".

**Update** Хорошо, допустим есть только стилистическая разница. Как возникло это стилистическое различие? Возможно дело в происхождении этих слов?

Тогда еще вопрос: есть ли различия в происхождении этих слов? Может быть слово "раба" пришло из церковно-славянского, а "рабыня" возникло позже? Можно ли это подтвердить или опровергнуть?

Comment: может это было по-болгарски? :) "Раба" - слуга. Не всё кириллицей по-русски.

Comment: @garik Очень интересно что вы упомянули болгарский. [Вот здесь](http://www.textology.ru/article.aspx?aId=177) пишут что "Церковно-славянский язык был живым языком в Болгарии IX — Х веков, т.е. не отличался ничем существенным от разговорного языка болгарского населения".

Comment: где-то там надо копать...:)

Comment: @Artemix - Если там такое пишут, то не верьте, это неправда. Цитируемая вами книга сильно устарела, сейчас даже термин "церковно-славянский язык" не применяется к языку первых переводов, его называют старославянским. Так вот этот язык никогда не был разговорным, он искусственно создан, это искусственный язык. Вопрос может стоять только о том, на основе какого тогдашнего славянского диалекта он создан. Скорее всего это диалект солунских славян, города Солоники (Солунь), откуда родом были Кирилл и Мефодий. Только вот тогдашние солунские славяне - это не болгары, а предки современных македонцев.

Comment: As a funny side note, `рабица` is not used in the modern language in this sense, but a well-known wire fence pattern is called [`сетка Рабица`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Раба" уместно звучит только в поэтично-пафосном контексте — упомянутая "раба божья", а также, например, "раба любви", "я твоя раба!". "Рабыня" же — обозначения угнетённой женщины, можно и в переносном смысле.
Поскольку сериал про Изауру — любовный роман, то с этим, похоже, и связано мнение об альтернативной версии перевода, "Раба [любви] Изаура".

Comment: Интересно, как возникло это стилистическое различие? Может быть из-за происхождения слов? Например "раба" из церковно-славянского, а "рабыня" - более позднее из слова "раб"?

Comment: @Artemix - оба слова одинаково старые, оба встречаются в старославянских текстах, при этом "рабыня" изначально было "рабыни" (единственное число), все слова женского рода с суффиксом -ын- оканчивались на -и.

Comment: @YellowSky Тогда получается что именно употребление слова "раба" в Библии сделало его "высоким стилем". Википедия о церковно-славянском языке: "Многочисленные заимствования церковнославянских слов породили в русском языке своеобразное явление — фонетически выраженную стилевую разницу в парах слов одного и того же корня, например: золото/злато, город/град, рожать/рождать (первое слово каждой пары русское, второе заимствовано из церковнославянского). В образовавшихся таким образом синонимических парах церковнославянское заимствование обычно относится к более высокому стилю".

Comment: @Artemix - В Библии на церковнославянском употребляется и "раба" и "рабыня", причем иногда даже в соседних стихах, например, [Иеремия 34:11](http://azbyka.ru/biblia/?Jer.34&rc) - "рабыня", а через 5 стихов, в стихе 16 - "раба". Какое из них встречается чаще определить трудно, дело в том, что "раба" - это ещё и Род./Вин. падеж ед. ч. от слова "раб", встречается сотни раз, каждое такое слово искать в церковнославянском тексте мне трудновато, но у меня складывается впечатление, что оба слова встречаются одинаково часто.

Comment: @YellowSky Значит дело только в "рабе Божьей".

Comment: @КуЪ Похоже что название "Раба Изаура" было у оригинальнй книги Б. Гимараинса (написана в 1875), по крайней мере именно в такой форме оно [упоминается](http://feb-web.ru/feb/kle/kle-abc/ke1/ke1-7131.htm) в "Краткой литературной энциклопедии" 1962 г. издания.

Answer (score 3):

"Раба" -- архаизм с соответствующей окраской. Употребляется в том числе в составе устойчивых выражений: упомянутое "раба Божия", "Сама себя раба бьёт, что не чисто жнёт". В Русской Правде записано как "роба", через "о".

"Рабыня" -- более современное слово, но и оно употребляется сравнительно редко сейчас. Обычно в текстах про современное рабство я его не вижу.